# DMS-50763 ERROR in oracle weblogic 12 possible causes

Tags: java, runtime-error, weblogic12c

We've a cluster of 3 nodes running Oracle Weblogic 12.2.1.2.

Checking `weblogic.Stdout` log file, I've started to see tons of the following trace:

```
<Warning><oracle.dms.instrument><DMS-50763> <Attempt to create pre-existing noun /MY_DOMAIN/MY_CLUSTER_NODE_X/DEPLOY_NAME, of type wls_jaxrsapp_resources, with a conflicting type wls_ear.>
```

*MY_DOMAIN* is the configured domain in weblogic server, and *DEPLOY_NAME* is the name of my deployed war in the server.

Looking at Oracle documentation this error is described as:

> DMS-50763: Attempt to create pre-existing noun {0}, of type {1}, with
>   a conflicting type {2}.
>
> Cause: An attempt has been made to create a noun that already exists and has a type that is different from the current attempt to create it.
>
> Action: Correct the code responsible for creating this noun.
>
> Level: 1 Type: SET_AT_RUNTIME Impact: Other

This description looks confusing to me since the proposed action to solve the problem is about correcting the code, but I guess that error is related on how  internally the server uses the war name for more than one resource.

I checked if there is other war or artifact deployed with the same name but it's not. Furthermore I thought that `wls_ear` refers to the deploy war, and `wls_jaxrsapp_resources` refers to some jaxb-rest resource (messages, stubs...) but I'm not even sure. I'm only guessing because I didn't find anything about it in the Oracle's documentation with this nomenclature.

Can somebody explain this error with more detail to put me in the right direction?